# Split file during writing

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

gurus!

A long time i can't found answer on following question: how hadoop splitting big file during writing. 
Example:
1) Block size 64 Mb
2) File size 128 Mb (flat file, containing text).

When i writing file it's will be split at 2 part (file size / block size).
But... *Could occurrence following*
Block1 will be ended at 
...
word300 word301 **wo**
and Block 2 will be start
**rd302** word303
...
Write case will be

Block1 will be ended at 
...
word300 word301
and Block 2 will be start
word302** word303
...

or can you link at the place where write about hadoop splitting algoritms.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks [this](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce) wiki page, hadoop `InputFormat` will read the last line of the FileSplit past the split boundary and, when reading other than the first FileSplit, it ignores the content up to the first newline.

Answer (score 0):

The file will be split arbitrarily based on bytes. So it will likely split it into something like `wo` and `rd302`.

This is not a problem you have to typically worried about and is how the system is designed. The `InputFormat` and `RecordReader` part of a MapReduce job deal with records split between record boundaries.